# open luakit windows of specific size from shell script

Tags: shell, browser, lua, raspberry-pi

can anybody help me achieving this with luakit?
I'm running raspbian on rpi3 and for my application I need one luakit window constantly running in full screen mode and triggered by a bash script, I want another browser window open from time to time in a certain size e.g. 800x600. Would be nice if I could also determine the position of the second window.

I was able to launch luakit in full screen or specific size by overwriting the window function in my rc.lua config. I then launch luakit with either the one or the other rc.lua file (-c parameter) . However if one instance of luakit is already running, the second luakit window uses the config of the first one that is already running.

Can I somehow trigger the window size of a new luakit window from bash script?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem: instead of giving the browser instance the window size, I let itself decide whether or not to launch in fullscreen by checking the URL.

in my rc.lua I added `require "userconf"` and created a file userconf.lua in which I have overwritten the function `window.new` like so:

```
function window.new(uris)
    local w = window.build()

    -- Set window metatable
    setmetatable(w, {
    __index = function (_, k)
        -- Check widget structure first
        local v = rawget(w, k)
        if v then return v end
        -- Call each window index function
        for _, index in ipairs(window.indexes) do
            v = index(w, k)
            if v then return v end
        end
    end,
    })

    -- Setup window widget for signals
    lousy.signal.setup(w)

    -- Call window init functions
    for _, func in pairs(window.init_funcs) do
    func(w)
    end

    -- Call window init functions
    for _, func in pairs(window.init_funcs) do
    func(w)
    end

    -- Populate notebook with tabs
    for _, uri in ipairs(uris or {}) do
    w:new_tab(w:search_open(uri), false)
    end

    -- Make sure something is loaded
    if w.tabs:count() == 0 then
    w:new_tab(w:search_open(globals.homepage), false)
    end

    -- Set initial mode
    w:set_mode()

    -- Show window
    w.win:show()

    -- we check the url, if it points to the URL i want to see in fullscreen we launch in fullscreen otherwise we leave the default.
    -- open myapplication.html in fullscreen, every other window in normal mode
    w.win.fullscreen = false
    for _, uri in ipairs(uris or {}) do
            if string.match(uri, "myapplication.html") then
                    print "got myapplication.html"
                    w.win.fullscreen = true
            end
    end

    return w
end
```

It's probably not a 100% solution, but for me it's ok